# How to configure paper-input-container (polymer mixin) style outside of custom component?

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

We are trying to turn off paper input container style so that we can have all around border for input box and no animation on focus.

In custom polymer component, we were able to get what we want by disable the following mixin in custom polymer component style section:

--paper-input-container-underline
--paper-input-container-underline-focused

However, when copying the same style section out onto html and use paper-input-container, it is not taking. Is there a way to apply these mixin outside of custom polymer component? I am guessing my css syntax is wrong.

```
<style>
    paper-input-container{
        --paper-input-container-underline: {visibility: hidden};
        --paper-input-container-underline-focused: {visibility: hidden};
    }
</style>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you meant you moved the style into `index.html`...

First, CSS mixins and properties from `index.html` are only applied in Polymer when they're in `custom-style`s:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  ...
</style>
```

Second, your CSS selector needs to be adjusted to target the `paper-input-container`, as `paper-input-container` alone won't work. If you want to target only `paper-input-container`s in `x-foo` elements, then you'd write:

```
x-foo {
  --paper-input-container-underline: {visibility: hidden};
  --paper-input-container-underline-focused: {visibility: hidden};
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ENxPZP?editors=1000)

Or if you want to target all `paper-input-container`s in any element, you'd use `:root` (deprecated) or `html` as your selector:

```
html {
  --paper-input-container-underline: {visibility: hidden};
  --paper-input-container-underline-focused: {visibility: hidden};
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/GNRorQ?editors=1000)

Comment: Note: in 2.0 the ```<style is="custom-style">``` will be depricated and the ```<custom-style>``` element will be the replacement. The 1.7+ will have the cutom-style element for preparing the upgrade.